# Pro/Con for Salesforce Send (Report vs Campaign)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign-member, send-definition

Are there any Pro/Con for Salesforce Sends using Marketing Cloud Connect between Reports and Campaigns?

Why would you send to a Report versus send to a Campaign?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Report get refreshed automatically at the time of sending. Without Process Builder the update a camapaign, the Campaigns will have the same number of members.

Also something to look at is the ROI. SFMC is not strong there so leveraging campaign and assigning a budget can help for reporting.